# Adding several target jobs to my CV

Tags: resume, job-search

I've been working for several years as a Web Developer and Infographic Design. Sometimes, as Content Editor.

Is it a good idea to add these three jobs in the "Target Jobs" fields of my CV?

Comment: I do not think you should have target jobs on your CV. A CV is a history of your work/education experience to date - not about the future

Answer (score 2):

Many people have an Objective section. It is typically one sentence that focuses less on job title and more on atmosphere and context:

> To use my web development skills in a fast-paced, high-stakes team where I can continue to learn and grow
>
> To join a team of dedicated web developers where I can lead large projects and integrate my infographic and content development skills

You describe the team, the company, the projects that you would like to be part of. You talk about long term things like rising to management, or learning something specific. And you flatter the people you're applying to a little, since they read your resume and think "if Hasan applied here, given this objective, Hasan must think we are fast-paced or leading-edge or vibrant!"

At their worst, Objective sections are content-free. They essentially say "I want a job and it would be cool if I could use the skills I already have." You can write a good one, and it may help with the occasional employer who ignores cover letters but circulates the resume, to someone who likes what's in your Objective. But a job title alone, or a list of three job titles, is never going to do that.

Work hard to make a sentence - one sentence! - that fits this pattern:

> Objective: To work in [or join, or lead] a [bunch of adjectives that are true for you] [team or company or department] where I can [long term things you want to do like create amazing web sites, change the future of advertising]

Taking the time to write that out will be good for you. Even if you don't put it in your resume, you can use it when deciding to apply, you can use it when people say "why do you want to work here", you can use it when people say "tell me a little about yourself" and it will generally be very good for you to know what you want and be able to say it succinctly. Just don't say something cliche ridden that would apply to anyone. **Make it real, make it about you and what you genuinely want.** That can be scary, but in the long run it's good.